# Name for seemingly incomplete sentences

Tags: terminology, sentences

I remember reading about sentences that naturally seem incomplete (ending in the middle as if the second half were missing), but are actually grammatically correct. The listener/reader just wrongly assumed some words to be either nouns or verbs.

I cannot find them now as I don't remember what they were called. I just remember they had a page on wikipedia.

Comment: Are you thinking of a run-on sentence? That is not grammatically 'correct', usually because of a missing (and essential) part of speech. The writer may be just hasty or distracted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are called [garden-path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) and the definition is more or less what you said: "The reader is lured into a parse that turns out to be a dead end or yields a clearly unintended meaning."

Comment: Just to be clear: garden-path sentences don’t necessarily end ‘in the middle’ of the sentence due to the misparsing – sometimes it’s the other way around, where the sentence continues after you expect it to be finished instead.

Comment: [Here's a list to check](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gardenpath.pdf). Notice that this is largely a phenomenon of writing; in speech these would not be confusing and we'd parse them straightforwardly without ever noticing the possible problem, because the intonation and rhythm would be different.

Comment: @jlawler Not disambiguated 100% of the time, but yes, usually.